# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner unit test does not work. Error: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, maven, junit, spring-test, spring-restcontroller

I am very new to Spring. We have Spring Rest API i.e. model, controller and service. Everything works, when I type 'mvn install' it will compile, package and deploy to local weblogic. Problem comes only when I write unit test under `com.gm.apms.test` and write `ExampleControllerTest.java` using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` I get error called `ApplicationContext not found`. This Spring application use JNDI and I even wrote the jdbc connection on `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` and file name is `datasource-testcontext.xml` I am not sure how to make application connect to DB directly using jdbc on unit test run but use `JNDI` when deployed. Any help is much appreciate.

ExampleControllerTest.java

```
    package com.gm.apms.test;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
    import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

    import com.gm.apms.common.service.SystemTypesService;

    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
(
  {
   "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml"
  }
)
    public class ExampleControllerTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired 
        SystemTypesService systemTypesService;

        @Autowired 
        private WebApplicationContext ctx;

        @Before  
        public void init() {  
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();
        } 

        @Test
        public void checkifSomethingWorkingGood() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/services/regions"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }

    }
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- base package containing the Spring Controller classes -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gm.apms" />

    <!-- Spring MVC Annotation -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="com.gm.apms.common.ContentTypeNegotiatingJsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!-- Sets up the Persistence Context -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- JNDI Based datasource -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/APMS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <!-- Spring EntityManagerFactory that is managed by the J2EE Container -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu_apms" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
        <!-- value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Injects the EntityManager Instance for methods/fields with the @PersistentContext 
        annotation -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <!-- JPA Based Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Annotation driven Transaction Manager -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Translator class that maps Javax Persistence Exceptions to Spring JDBC 
        Exceptions -->
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" />
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- Decide the file sizes -->
    </bean>


    <!-- DAO and Service Beans -->
    <bean id="salesOrderService" class="com.gm.apms.order.service.SalesOrderServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="systemTypesService" class="com.gm.apms.common.service.SystemTypesServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

here is the error I got:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.gm.apms.test.ExampleControllerTest
2015-05-20 20:59:46 INFO  DefaultTestContextBootstrapper:256 - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
2015-05-20 20:59:46 INFO  DefaultTestContextBootstrapper:182 - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@157c76a, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1e53a48, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@556aa9, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1cdbaf7, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@1adc6a5]
2015-05-20 20:59:46 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]
2015-05-20 20:59:47 INFO  GenericApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5211ef: startup date [Wed May 20 20:59:47 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-05-20 20:59:47 WARN  GenericApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 56 more
2015-05-20 20:59:47 ERROR TestContextManager:215 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1e53a48] to prepare test instance [com.gm.apms.test.ExampleControllerTest@e62f8]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 56 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.022 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  checkifSomethingWorkingGood(com.gm.apms.test.ExampleControllerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to achieve this is to use Spring's support for *bean definition profiles*.

Define your `DataSource` beans like this:

```xml
<beans ...>

    <!-- JNDI Based datasource -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/APMS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <beans profile="test">
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@100.100.100.20:1622:abc" />
            <property name="username" value="XXXX" />
            <property name="password" value="XXXX" />
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

And then declare your test class like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ExampleControllerTest {
```

That should solve your problem elegantly! ;)

For more detailed information, see my [Spring 3.1 M2: Testing with @Configuration Classes and Profiles](http://www.swiftmind.com/de/2011/06/22/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/) blog post.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: In the linked application above, `ExampleControllerTest` is missing the `@ContextConfiguration` and `@ActiveProfiles` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `@ContextConfiguration`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/path/to/spring-config.xml")
public class ExampleControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired 
    SystemTypesService systemTypesService;

    @Autowired 
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    @Before  
    public void init() {  
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();
    } 

    @Test
    public void checkifSomethingWorkingGood() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/services/regions"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: i did that, but still i got error. I have updated the question to show you error and contextconfiguration. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolved it by tweaking the spring-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- base package containing the Spring Controller classes -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gm.apms" />

    <!-- Spring MVC Annotation -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="com.gm.apms.common.ContentTypeNegotiatingJsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!-- Sets up the Persistence Context -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Spring EntityManagerFactory that is managed by the J2EE Container -->
     <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu_apms" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
        <!-- value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>jdbc/APMS</value>
        </property>
        <!--  fallback to a local datasource if we are not in the container -->
        <property name="defaultObject" ref="developmentDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="developmentDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@100.100.100.20:1622:abc" />
        <property name="username" value="XXXX" />
        <property name="password" value="XXXX" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Injects the EntityManager Instance for methods/fields with the @PersistentContext 
        annotation -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <!-- JPA Based Transaction Manager -->
     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 


    <!-- Annotation driven Transaction Manager -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Translator class that maps Javax Persistence Exceptions to Spring JDBC 
        Exceptions -->
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" />
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- Decide the file sizes -->
    </bean>


    <!-- DAO and Service Beans -->
    <bean id="salesOrderService" class="com.gm.apms.order.service.SalesOrderServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="systemTypesService" class="com.gm.apms.common.service.SystemTypesServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```